# Can I create multiple associations between two entities in Entity Framework 5, c#?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-relationship

E.g. I have 2 entities:

```
public class Department
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

I know I can associate (as I already did:) `Department.Employees` with `Employee.Id` (and inverse: `Employee.Department` with `Department.Id`).

**Questions:**
1) Is this one or two associations?

2) Can I create the second association between `Department.Manager` and `Employee.Id`? Don' want to store Managers in another table so they are also stored in Employee table and have in `Position` field "Manager".

Comment: You probably want Manager to inherit from Employee?

Comment: @Sam Leach, thank You) Don't know how I missed this) But will I be able to store managers in Employee table?

Comment: No, see my answer. Just define the relationship as one to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the relationship as follows.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
        .HasRequired(a => a.Manager)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.EmployeeId);
}
```

You want them virtual too if you want lazy loading and change tracking.

```
public class Department
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }
}
```